# Modify response before it is sent to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

***Node 16.14.2, Express 4.18.1***

I've seen plenty of people modifying res.send to perform actions before the response is sent to the client.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    originalSend = res.send;
    res.send = function (body) {
        // Do something with the body...
        originalSend.call(this, body);
    };
    next();
});
```

However, if I send data other than 'body', it result in some error.

```
originalSend = res.send;

res.send = function (body) {
    originalSend.call(this, body);
    // Works fine

    originalSend.call(this, { ...body, "USER": req.user });
    // RangeError: Too many properties to enumerate

    originalSend.call(this, {})
    // RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

    originalSend.call(this, { "Foo": "bar" })
    // RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
}
```

I've tried pretty much everything, 'body' is the only thing that will go through, how come ?

**UPDATE:**

**Seems like converting the data to a string solved the problem.**
I still don't know why there was a problem in the first place since send is supposed to be able to handle objects and other types of data (which works fine outside this function definition in my app).

```
originalSend.call(this, JSON.stringify({ ...body, "Foo": "bar" }));
```

Comment: I tried in my typescript code and it says `res.send` expects the return value. Please if you need to return something. P.S. returning `originalSend` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```js
const originalSend = res.send;
res.send = function (body) {
    // Do something with the body...
    originalSend.call(this, JSON.stringify({ ...JSON.parse(body), 'USER': 'user' }));

    //console.log(typeof body)
};
```

**Reason:**

`body` param in the function has a `string` type. That means the `originalSend.call()` accepts string value only. So to combine your custom values with the dynamic response, you have to convert `body` to JSON, so that you can use `...` (spread operator) and then convert the entire 2nd param to `call` to stringified object.

Comment: body param is of type of anything you passed, in my case it's an array. Also, res.send doesn't only accept string, see the doc [send()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send). Converting my data to string did work though, `originalSend.call(this, JSON.stringify({ ...body, "USER": req.user }))`, thanks

Comment: I was trying with JSON so the type of body inside our custom send function should be an object, instead, it returned a string. Since we are overriding the method `send`, to modify the original response, it is possible that it has a different behaviour to support many types. This is my assumption, as passing the object in the `.call()` method also did not work when I tried your snippet, so I converted to string.